# submit and show records without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form, which submit data in to table and show them on the same page. But it reloads page.

I want submit and show data without reloading page. I have read so many AJAX 
scripts. But I am confused .

Can any one help please?

```
<form action="viewblog.php" method="post"> 
<h3 class="contact_title">Leave a Comment</h3> 
<div class="contact_form">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-4 columns">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">    
 <textarea cols="10" rows="15" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea> 
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button right" value="Add a comment" />
</div>    
</div>    
</div>    
</form>    

 <?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{   
require"connection.php";

extract($_POST);


extract($_REQUEST);


mysql_query("insert into comment values('','',Now(),'$name','$comment')") or die 


(mysql_error());


echo"Comment Inserted Succesfully !";


}


?> 




 <?php



  include('connection.php');


     extract($_REQUEST);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM enteries;";


$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))


            {


                extract($row1);

?> 


<div class="comments">


                    <ol class="comment_list">




                        <!--comment item-->


                        <li class="com_item">


                            <div class="com_main">


                                <div class="com_content">


                                    <div class="com_meta">


                                        <span class="user_name"><a href="#"><?
php echo $name;  ?></a></span>


<span class="com_date"><?php echo date("D jS F Y ", strtotime($dateposted))  ?>

</span>

                                    </div>


                                    <p class="com_text"><?php echo $comment;  ?>
</p>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </li>

                    </ol>

                </div>

                <?php


            }


                ?>
```

Comment: Hire a developer (who isn't confused) to help you, while you focus on the marketing of whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: GOOGLE ajax form submit

Comment: You need to post some code. You are pobably using the submit button of the HTML form to trigger your AJAX. Make sure you are preventing the default behavior with preventDefault(); (assuming you are using jQuery)

Comment: Update record in the database through `ajax`. AND Show newly added data in table through `JavaScript`. Use `preventDefault();` for form

Answer (score 0):

PHP executes at server side, so Directly writing PHP and HTML combined won't make call without reload.

you need `JavaScript` to do AJAX call. 
You can use jQuery or JavaScript or any other library.

[This link](http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/introduction.php) will teach you basics about AJAX.

Comment: As soon as the link you've mentioned becomes obsolete, this answer won't be of much use.

Comment: OP doesn't know, otherwise he would not post here. so I have mentioned just.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form> 
    <h3 class="contact_title">Leave a Comment</h3> 
    <div class="contact_form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <input type="text" name="name" id='name' placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 columns">    
                <textarea cols="10" rows="15" id='comment' name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' class="button right" value="Add a comment" />
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</form>    
<script>
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&comment='+ comment;
        $.ajax({
        url: viewblog.php,
        type:'POST',
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }               
        });
});</script>
```

**viewblog.php**

```
<?
$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];

$query="INSERT INTO TableName SET NameColumnName='$name', CommentColumnName='$comment'";

//Execute Query Here.. 

echo "Comment Submitted Succesfully";

?>
```